# Unable to do partitioning through gparted

Tags: gparted, partitioning

[image: GPART screenshot]

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and after installation when I'm trying to partition the disk, the maximum I'm able to allocate is 48MB.

Comment: Your disk is showed with 238.47GB, you have two usable partitions `/dev/sda1` ( 487MB ) and `/dev/sda5` ( 238GB ). The two partitions use all available space, so there is no space left for an additional partition, unless you shrink `/dev/sda5` to free up some space.

Comment: If you were trying to use LVM, you didn't install Ubuntu correctly. There's an option at install time which allow you to create LVM partitions/etc. However, if this is your first Ubuntu install, I'd recommend against using LVM, and using the standard install instead. If you haven't got any data in Ubuntu yet, I'd just reinstall, and use the wipe disk choice (Ubuntu by itself).